# Prevent keyboard dismissal on UITableView cell touch

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a `UITableView` with several rows with buttons inside.
The same page contains `UITextField` control.
Once I activated the `TextField` input I want to keep it active even if I press the button within a cell within UITableView.

Right now any touch on `UITableView` dismiss my keyboard and doesn't trigger `UITouchUpInside`. I tried to disable `Cancellable content touch` but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a custom gesture recognizer

```
var tap:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "DismissKeyboard")
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

then add the action

```
func DismissKeyboard() {
    self.view.endEditing(false)
}
```

If the user taps anywhere on screen, it wont dismiss the keyboard since it wont end editing.

Answer (score 1):

Set a `UITextFieldDelegate` for your `UITextField` and implement `textFieldShouldEndEditing` and return NO/false.

This will prevent loss of first responder status (which is what pops up the keyboard).

Comment: will the button tap event we triggered in this case? I need my command to be executed still